# How to check specific file and run another python script

Tags: python, watchdog

I want to use watchdog for monitoring specific filename in directory for run specific python script.

**for example:**

First, I want to use watchdog for monitor all of .avi file.

If name of .avi file in path (C:/User/AAxxx/video/) is : ABxxx_11.avi, I want to run ABxxx_11.py

If name of .avi file in path (C:/User/BBxxx/video/) is : CDxxx_22.avi, I want to run CDxxx_22.py

If name of .avi file in path (C:/User/CCxxx/video/) is : EFxxx_33.avi, I want to run EFxxx_33.py

And I want to pass sub-folder directory of AAxxx, BBxxx amd CCxxx folder.
I want to focus only .avi file.

Now I have only watchdog for monitor .avi file and run python only one script.
please see as below.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler
                    
class Watcher:
    def __init__(self, path, filename):
        self.observer = Observer()
        self.path = path
        self.filename = filename

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler(self.filename)
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.path, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print("Error")

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        super(Handler, self).__init__(
            patterns=[filename],
            ignore_patterns=["*.tmp"],
            ignore_directories=True,
            case_sensitive=False,
        )

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print(
            "[{}] noticed: [{}] on: [{}] ".format(
                time.asctime(), event.event_type, event.src_path
            )
        )
        #process1 = subprocess.Popen(["python", "ABxxx_11.py"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = "C:/Users/xxx/AAxxx/video/"
    filename = "*.avi"

    w = Watcher(path, filename)
    w.run()
```

Comment: You've some context written above, but may I know what's your question?

Comment: @Han Thank you for your response. I want to know. How to adjust my code to use watchdog for monitoring specific filename in directory for run specific python script.

Comment: refer to my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your code to run, so I hardcoded the values. Just check for the modified and created files, get the file name and execute the python script accordingly.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler


class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = "C:/Users/test/AAxxx/video"

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

    def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(5)
        except:
            self.observer.stop()
            print "Error"

        self.observer.join()


class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':
            # Take any action here when a file is first created.
            print "Received created event - %s." % event.src_path
            if ".avi" in event.src_path:
                print "run this file ->" + str(event.src_path.rsplit('\\')[1].split('.')[0]) + ".py"

        elif event.event_type == 'modified':
            # Taken any action here when a file is modified.
            print "Received modified event - %s." % event.src_path
            if ".avi" in event.src_path:
                print "run this file ->" + str(event.src_path.rsplit('\\')[1].split('.')[0]) + ".py"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

when I create a new .avi file in the path, the following is the output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. It' work when I use full of avi filename but If I want to use filename in your code like a glob path (Ext.:  if "AB*_11.avi " in event.src_path:) How I can change this code support whatever name in (*) symbol.

Comment: There's a easy way. If you are sure that's the pattern, just use -> `if "AB" in event.src_path and "_11.avi" in event.src_path:` A more elegant way is to use regular expressions to check.